# Howe to Add Dynamic Caption to a Video?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to create and add a caption to a video without creating .vtt file?

Here is what I want to try:
So, I am creating a video call app (just for practice purposes), and I am wondering if I can display the username of the callers by making a caption or subtitle in the video that will run in the entire stream time.

Adding subtitles is possible using a tracking element, but I need to create .vtt file, and I don't want that. What I want is to create the track in the code. I have this code below but it is not showing in the video.

```
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        video.play();
        track = this.addTextTrack("captions", "English", "en");
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(0, 500, username));
    });
```

Summary of the questions:

1. Is my goal possible? (Proceed if yes)
2. How to add a caption by coding it and not by using a file?
3. How to play it in the entire stream time (from 00:00 to the end of the stream)?

Comment: `this` inside an arrow function is not the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in arrow function points to window. You can access video element by event.target or just use you video variable.

```js
   video.srcObject = stream;
   video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        video.play();
        const track = video.addTextTrack("captions", "English", "en");
        track.mode = "showing";
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(0, 500, username));// or TextTrackCue instead VTTCue
    });
```

Comment: Hi! I edited my code to as suggested and used TextTrackCue 
`track.addCue(new TextTrackCue("Test text", 0, 1000, "", "", "", true));` but it's still not showing in the stream. I also tried it in this test link from w3school https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_addtexttrack. but also not working.
Can you help me?

Comment: Never mind, it worked. I just added `track.mode = "showing";` to my code.

Comment: add track.mode = "showing";

Comment: Is there any way to flip the caption? Cause I am mirroring my video and my caption is also mirrored. Also, no track tag displayed in the html.

Comment: To display track. just add it to DOM by e.g by using append. To reflect subtitles you should take video length and reverse time of subtitles. If video have 1h and you have text at 15m. then time to end is 45 so your subtitles should be on 45m.